# Tagging master branch in GitLab and adding it in Julia leads an incorrect tag info

Tags: git, gitlab, julia

I have been developing a Julia package on GitLab for a while, and along the way, I tagged certain versions, like v0.7.0, v0.7.1, ... The current master branch was just tagged as v1.0.0 using my GitLab repository website. Now, when I added this project (the GitLab master branch) to use in Julia, the corresponding version information of this package in Julia's `Manifest.toml` says: "v0.0.0", not "v1.0.0" as I tagged the master branch on GitLab. Why does this happen and how can I set the consistent tag (or version info) of my package under Julia? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If the package is public it would be very helpful with a link to the repository. Also, when  you say that you add the package, what do you do then?

Comment: @fredrikekre: sorry, my package is not in the public domain at the moment. My students and I are using and developing this package, and what I meant by "adding the package to Julia" is to use that package  by adding as usual, e.g.., ```(v1.0) pkg> add https://gitlab.com/xxx/yyy.git``` or ```(v1.0) pkg> add git@gitlab.com:xxx/yyy.git```

Answer (score 0):

`git tags` are (mostly) irrelevant for Pkg. When you `pkg> add url` you will get the master branch of the package. The version that is used in version resolution of an added branch is determined by the `version` entry in your `Project.toml` file.

Comment: Thanks. But the ```version``` entries of the packages are written in my ```Manifest.toml``` rather than my ```Project.toml``` . I already knew that. But my question is how to change this ```version``` entry automatically without manually editing ```Manifest.toml```.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. Unless you can publish the code it would be very nice to add a constructed example to the original post.

Comment: After adding my package called ```MTSG.jl```, in my Project.toml file contains the following line: ```MTSG = "1009ea13-4db1-5831-9adb-c34a14008ad8"``` while my Manifest.toml file contains the following: ```[[MTSG]]
deps = ["Arpack", "Distances", "Distributions", "JLD2", "LinearAlgebra", "Plots", "Reexport", "SparseArrays", "Statistics"]
git-tree-sha1 = "49609ffeccd9631e4d33b808d4788566f3d10895"
repo-rev = "master"
repo-url = "https://gitlab.com/BoundaryValueProblems/MTSG.jl.git"
uuid = "1009ea13-4db1-5831-9adb-c34a14008ad8"
version = "0.0.0"``` I want the last line to be updated.

Comment: Right, so that line is governed by the `version` field in your `Project.toml` file. For example, if you `pkg> add https://github.com/fredrikekre/Sandbox.jl.git` you will get version `0.1` since that is what is defined here: https://github.com/fredrikekre/Sandbox.jl/blob/c25256383a242e4549566d9201f51e5d72776529/Project.toml#L4

Comment: Thanks! My ```Project.toml``` file is in my ```~/.julia/environment``` folder, and my GitLab project repository does not have its own ```Project.toml``` unlike your example repo, ```Sandbox.jl```. Is there any way to create ```Project.toml``` file under GitLab repo? Or do I need to create that file manually and upload it to the GitLab repo?